# Katalon Studio: git cloning a repo to KS results in deleting my tests

Tags: git, automated-tests, katalon-studio

So, I know that you can git clone an empty repo to KS first, before creating your tests and then committing and pushing them up to github. However, what if I had created a bunch of automated tests, BEFORE deciding that I want to push them to github?

When I tried to git clone a repo to a KS project AFTER having already created an automated test, the test is then deleted and you can only work from a clean slate (provided the repo is empty).

Is there any way I can save the automated tests I already created?

I know you cannot share tests between projects, so the option to create a new project, git clone the repo and then import the tests, is out.

Answer (score 0):

First, you associate your project with Git by "sharing" (click "Share Project" from "Git" menu in the toolbar - https://docs.katalon.com/display/KD/Git+Integration). Don't clone.

You create a new branch on Github or similar, then push to the new branch.